# Assigning case to case teams from community

Tags: service-cloud-console, customer-community, assignment-rules, case-teams

Whenever a case is created from the Community User, I am getting this error "Can't Perform this Operation  You can't perform this operation with the selected user type."

As per the knowledge article this is due to user creating the case lacking access to User table. But in my case, OWD on user is read-only, so why i am getting this error? Is there any other setting which needs to be done?

Also, in our assignment rule we have a case team assigned. The assignment rule is working when case is not created via portal. Also, Assign using active assignment rules is checked and present on Page Layout.

Comment: Is this a customer community or some other kind? Upon saving the case, who becomes the owner of the case? Does it go into a queue, auto-assigned or assigned to the owner of the customer? If case is read only for that community user profile, obviously, they can't be the owner of the case when it's saved and someone else needs to have that r-w ability on their profile to take ownership.

Comment: sorry for the mess-up the OWD on case is private and on User is Read Only. The Issue is that case gets assigned to a queue when there are no case teams assigned to the case, but when i add a case team i am getting this issue. And this issue seems to be only coming when a case is created via the community. The assignment rule is working in case of email2case and web2case.

Comment: Do you have different record types assigned to cases depending on their source of origin? If so, you may need a separate rule for those that originate from community users.